# Conditional probability of uniform distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, uniform-distribution

Let X and Y be independent random variables, uniform on [0,1]. If the smaller is less that 1/4, Find the conditional probability that larger is greater than 3/4.

My solution:

$P(\text{Required})=P(X>3/4|X>Y)P(X>Y)+P(Y>3/4|Y>X)$

Now

$P(X>3/4|X>Y)P(X>Y)=P(X>3/4,X>Y)=P(X>3/4, Y<1/4)=P(X>3/4)P(Y<1/4)=(1-3/4)(1/4-0)=1/16$

Similarly, $P(Y>3/4|Y>X) = 1/16$

Hence, $P(\text{Required})=1/8$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:

- $\Pr\left(\max\left(X,Y\right)>\frac{3}{4}\mid\min\left(X,Y\right)<\frac{1}{4}\right)\Pr\left(\min\left(X,Y\right)<\frac{1}{4}\right)=\Pr\left(\max\left(X,Y\right)>\frac{3}{4}\wedge\min\left(X,Y\right)<\frac{1}{4}\right)$
- $\Pr\left(\max\left(X,Y\right)>\frac{3}{4}\wedge\min\left(X,Y\right)<\frac{1}{4}\right)=\Pr\left(X>\frac{3}{4}\wedge Y<\frac{1}{4}\right)+\Pr\left(Y>\frac{3}{4}\wedge X<\frac{1}{4}\right)$
- $\Pr\left(\min\left(X,Y\right)<\frac{1}{4}\right)=1-\Pr\left(\min\left(X,Y\right)>\frac{1}{4}\right)=1-\Pr\left(X>\frac{1}{4}\wedge Y>\frac{1}{4}\right)$

---

You will end up with $\frac27$.

Split up the square $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ in $4\times4=16$ smaller squares. Condition $\min(X,Y)<\frac14$ demands to focus on $7$ of these smaller squares and in $2$ of them it is true that $\max(X,Y)>\frac34$.

Comment: The small squares explanation is excellent, +1 for this.

Comment: I got it. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Did, I'm sorry I thought I already had.

Comment: @Did Thanks! I am always somewhat reticent if it comes to asking for acceptance of my own answer (it might be false humility). If someone else stimulates to accept my answer then that gives a nice feeling :-).

Comment: I share your feeling about one's own answers. In the present case, I think the answer is good and I wanted to mention it.